# Manually add points to a LAS object with lidR

Tags: lidr

Using lidR, given a LAS object, read from a LAS file:

```
las <- readLAS(point_cloud_file)
```

and points (extracted from a shapefile):

```
shp <- st_read(shp_file)
pts <- st_coordinates(shp)
```

I would like to add (append) these points to the LAS object (assuming both `las` and `shp` share the same CRS)

How can I get to that?

Comment: This is doable but not trivial. First, shapefiles do not support XYZ points. Do you input Z = 0? Does the table of attributes matters? Please clarify your question

Comment: Yes I do have 3D vectors in the shapefile (PolygonZ or LineStringZ), the table of attributes does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not as easy as it might seem. From `pts` which is a `matrix` you can extract the columns. Here I'm using `runif` to make a reproducible example

```r
library(lidR)
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(LASfile)


X = runif(1000, 684766, 684993)
Y = runif(1000, 5017773, 5018007)
Z = runif(1000, 0, 30)
data = data.frame(X,Y,Z)
```

Then we can make a `LAS` object with `LAS()` and we provide the header of `las` to create object of the same format

```r
las2 = LAS(data, las@header)
```

This triggers some warning because we input some inccorectly quantized coordinates. Check the output of `las_check()`

```r
las_check(las2)
```

We can fix that

```r
las2 = las_quantize(las2, TRUE)
las2 = las_update(las2)

las_check(las2)
```

Now if we want to combine the `las` and `las2` they must have the same columns. We need to make them manually. Here if you load only `XYZ` in `las` the job is easier.

```r
las2@data$gpstime = 0
las2@data$Intensity = 0L
las2@data$ReturnNumber = 1L
las2@data$NumberOfReturns = 1L
las2@data$ScanDirectionFlag = 0L
las2@data$EdgeOfFlightline = 0L
las2@data$Classification = 0L
las2@data$Synthetic_flag = FALSE
las2@data$Keypoint_flag = FALSE
las2@data$Withheld_flag = FALSE
las2@data$ScanAngleRank = 0L
las2@data$UserData = 0L
las2@data$PointSourceID = 0L
```

We can bind the two objects

```r
las3 = rbind(las, las2)
```

Comment: Generic solution starting from a matrix, it does the job, thank you!

Comment: After setting the synthetic flag to FALSE, is there another way to discover synthetic points?